# Homebrew does not install on my m1 mac book

Tags: homebrew, macos-ventura

```
work@Krishnas-MacBook-Pro ~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
curl: (28) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 after 75222 ms: Operation timed out
```

I have been getting this error consistently from the past 4 days. I am not able to install Homebrew  because of this connection timeout. When I try to hit the URL on my browser too, it does not work.

[image: 1]

Can someone help me with this as I need to download MySql from brew. Normal installation does not let me connect with python SQLAlchemy. Thanks in advance!

Tried searching for Homebrew pkg installation but does not look like it exists.

Comment: I had this issue yesterday, I think `raw.githubusercontent.com` was down for a bit

Comment: @ellis is it still down?